# SQL using same codes table for two different columns

Tags: sql

I have a table (Foo) that has two columns that store a code value from a codes table:

```
id - code1 - code2
1  -  CC    -  DD
```

The Codes table:

```
  Name         -   Code - Grouping
 Call Center   -    CC  -    22
 County        -    DD  -    54
```

I need a SQL that will pull 'Call Center' and 'County' based on the first table. It is assumed that I know Foo.code1 necessarily uses Codes.Grouping=22 and Foo.code2 uses Codes.Grouping=54.

I'm trying to write one SQL that will return both values.

Comment: it is not clear what you want to give as input and what do you expect to get back - and in which form (i.e. one row or multiple rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select name from codes c inner join foo f on c.code = f.code1 or c.code = f.code2
```

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc837/1)

Comment: +1 for sqlfiddle! did not know the service. I expanded my answer using your fiddle!

Comment: I'm trying to edit where i get one result set back, with two columns.

Comment: interestingly you accepted this answer of tuffkid where you get ONE column with TWO rows... But it is good to see that you got what you wanted nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure if this is the answer to your question, because I don't know exactly what you mean. I guess however, that you want to get both codes and groupings for an id value of your Foo table. For this I would

```
SELECT Foo.id, 
       C1.Name AS code1_name, C1.Code AS code1_code, 
       C1.Grouping AS code1_grouping, 
       C2.Name AS code2_name, C2.Code AS code2_code, 
       C2.Grouping AS code2_grouping 
  FROM Foo 
       INNER JOIN Codes AS C1 ON C1.Code = Foo.code1 
       INNER JOIN Codes AS C2 ON C2.Code = Foo.code2
  WHERE Foo.id = 1;
```

expanding tuffkid sqlfiddle[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bc837/2/0)